# Permission denied accessing windows firewall

Tags: windows, firewall

It doesn't matter who I am logged in as I am getting the following error in the mmc console when I launch the firewall advanced settings

**There was an error opening the Windows Firewall with Advanced Security snap in**
You do not have the correct permissions to open the Windows Firewall with Advanced
Security console, You must be a member of the Administrators group or the Network
Operators  group to perform this task. For more information, contact your system
administrator. Error code: 0x5.

Ive tried processmonitor to identify what permission is being denied but no luck.

If I run netsh directly I get access denied as well.

This is running windows server 2008 SP2. And yes I was running as an administrator.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

What OS?
Are you under an Administrator account ?

may be a malware that have disabled access to firewall settings, you could try to scan your PC with an anti-malware like MalwareBytes.

Comment: Added to the question w2k8 SP2 and yes was an admin

Comment: this : http://www.winvistaclub.com/t61.html maybe can help you